# ASP.Net Core 2 how to trigger/call code after authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

How can I trigger some code right after authentication?
Let's say I want to give my application a single session constraint per user, for example. How can I implement it in ASP.Net Core 2.0?

## Update:

Clarification, I want to trigger code right after a user is considered authenticated (after .net authentication middleware have validated the user is who claims to be). I have not mentioned Middleware before because there might be an easier way, like an event, to trigger some code. Maybe the proper question would be if is there such event/way, or if I should manage it through a custom Middleware attached right after Authentication?

Comment: Please provide some code. In addition, your question is very broad, what do you mean after authentication? When the user is authenticated? or even if the user is anonymous? Why not calling the action in the controller, the controller is called after authentication. Please describe exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: I am sorry about the lack of details, although the second scenario you provided seems to fit my need. I am still reading it in order to know how to insert my custom middleware right after authentication. And yes, I meant to call a code after the user was properly authenticated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest scenario, is calling the method you want in any action in MVC controller. Actions are always called after authentication (I think this is not what you need, but the information your provided are very poor, as you did not mentioned exactly what do you mean by *right after authentication*).

The other possiblity (**which is probably what you want**), is to create a **middleware**, and add it to the pipeline exactly after authentication middleware. When you have your middleware in the pipeline, you can write to do what ever you want.

Middleware writing is well documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: I am glad that even with the lack of details, you provided 2 scenarios and possible solutions. Thank you! Just to confirm here as well, the second scenario you depicted, seems to fit my needs. I am still verifying a way to get it in a proper order and aware of the authentication result (I guess if authentication fails, it will redirect user and stop processing the middleware pipeline, but I am not sure yet).

Comment: @BrunoJulião, no if authentication failed, the pipeline just keeps going further (with User status to be not authenticated), but the other things will just keep happening normally. If you have a process which should happen almost every request for almost every action, then go with writing a Middleware and use it after authentication directly. If the authentication result is important, then just check the value of `HTTPContext.User`, and your middleware can decide what to do according to it.

Comment: Oh got it. You saved me a lot of time, @Mohammed. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: @BrunoJulião You are welcome :), if you have any related details or further small questions, you may edit your question and mention me and I will try to help.